# Wordpress + Timber + Twig

Tags: php, wordpress, symfony, twig, timber

in `index.php` (entry file) I have a `$context["home-page"] = home_url();` yet for some reason when I implement it as `<a href="{{ home-page }}">hello.com</a>.` When rendering, I get a "0" value in href attribute:  hello.com

when I dump that context value, I get this erroneous reply:

`\wp-content\themes\hello\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Extension\Debug.php:50:int 0`

Keep in mind that all the other contexts Work fine, such as:

- `$context["parent_link"] = get_template_directory_uri();`
- `$context["is_single"] = is_single();`

Is this somethin familiar to any of you?

Comment: the variable is not assigned in that case

Comment: @Calimero no... if the variable was not set, the variable would be null thus resulting in an empty string

Answer (score 1):

Please try it this way:

```
$context["home_page"]
```

Instead of

```
$context["home-page"]
```

In twig templates `{{ home-page }}` should be interpreted as a substraction of variable `home` with variable `page`.

Edit:
And like @DarkBee suggested you would have to define the variables before you can use them. That is why you get the error when debugging the context object.

Comment: You mean did u try `{{ _context['home-page'] }}` but your thoughts are correct. Good spot there

Comment: No I meant when you assign the value to the variable in your PHP file. Try with underscore and edit your twig file too: {{ home_page }}

Comment: Ah oh well that could solve the issue as well, but if OP realy insisted on `home-page` he/she should use the comment i posted. You could add it to your answer :)